# Configuration management in builds without source controlled config transformations

Tags: json, tfs, asp.net-core, azure-devops, .net-core

Given a configuration named "Data:ConnectionString" in appsettings.json file (ASP.NET Core application), how do I override this in the build? By overriding it can either be that there is a step which changes the value in appsettings.json before compilation during build, or that I override the parameter when using "dotnet test", or something else.

**More info:**

I have a ASP.NET Core application with standard configuration in appsettings.json. I do not want any connection string or sensitive data checked in the source control.

I am building my application using Visual Studio Team Service (cloud TFS). There is a step where tests are executed, and I want these tests to run against a remote service for which I do not want to check in the credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of extensions available on http://marketplace.visualstudio.com that will help you without any complicated ness.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YodLabs.VariableTasks

I like the Variable Tasks Pack that comes with:

- Set Variable Set a variable value and optionally apply a transformation to it.
- Set Variables with Credential Sets the username/password from an existing service endpoint
- Set Variable from JSON Extracts a value from JSON using JSONPath
- Set Variable from XML Extracts a value from XML using XPath
- Update Build Number Allows you to change a build number
  Increment Version Increments a semver version number

Super easy... You can also just search for "json" or "variable" to find other options...

Comment: Thx, ended up using https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sergeyzwezdin.magic-chunks

Answer (score 0):

Most popular ways:

- Use [app secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets)
- Use [`scripts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#scripts) section in your project.json. You have 4 events -
  precompile, postcompile, prepublish, postpublish

Comment: My problem is not overriding on local dev machine. My problem is when running as part of the build process. I dont't see how any of these options help in that case. How can you manage app secrets in team services?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the an environmental variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in the build to something like "Test". Create an appsettings.json file named appsettings.Test.Json. Then when you are setting up your configuration in Startup.cs do something like...

```
          var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
```

When the environmental variable is set to TEST, you new appsettings file will be loaded and can set the connection string to whatever you want.

Comment: But this is a normal approach where you would check in that appsettings file, I ask for an approach without checking in the "secrets", but overriding them in builds